# How embed a Youtube video in an Yahoo Map description box - Yahoo!Pipes

Tags: yahoo-pipes

How embed a Youtube video in an Yahoo Map description box (location extractor output) - Yahoo!Pipes
thanxs

Answer (score 0):

Buried in the javascript for the **[Yahoo Maps API](http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/flash/jsGettingStarted.html)** there is a function called **onMapInit(eventObj)** the variable called '*marker*' holds an array containg the text or HTML code for the pop up. The size of the box itself is controlled by an external CSS file held at Yahoo however by creating a local CSS entry in the page for a class called '*hover*' or '*.hover_content*' (I forget exactly what they call it now) you should be able to take control and make it big enough to hold a video.